# Oracle SQL - Iterative join

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle 12c.  I have a marketing application.  I have two tables of interest.  One is called Campaign_Definitions, and has one row for each of the marketing campaigns that will be run.  I have another table called TARGET, which has one row per family we wish to target.  The TARGET table will also have one COLUMN for each of the CAMPAIGNS in the CAMPAIGN_DEFINITION table, showing if that campaign is applicable for that family.  The code I need help with will be executed on a screen which just shows one family at a time.

The challenge I am running into is that I need to join in an odd way.  The END result I need is for a given family (Bob Smith in the picture below)show me each CAMPAIGN (as a separate row), and whether that campaign is applicable to that family.  While I am only showing 3 campaigns, there are about 90.  This can be either SQL or PL/SQL if that helps, as the data is going to the application in JSON.  Is there a clean way of doing this other than writing several lines of code for each of the 90 plays?

[image]

Comment: I don't know if it's possible in this case, but the design of the tables could be changed to make this easier and more normalized.   For example  Target could have the following columns "FamilyName", "Campaign" and "Indicator"   Then you can join.

Comment: Sounds like this might be a job for PIVOT and UNPIVOT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unpivot target table and then join to it:

```
with camp_def(camp_nm, prod, st_dt, end_dt)
as(
    select 'Easy_Tennis', 'Tennis Lessons', 'Jan-01', 'Mar-30' from dual union all
    select 'Summer_Vacations', 'Time Share', 'Apr-01', 'Sep-01' from dual union all
    select 'CPR_For_Beginners','CPR Class', 'Sep-01','Dec-01' from dual 
    )
,
Tgt(Fam_nm, Easy_tennis,Summer_Vacations,CPR_For_Beginners)
as(
    select 'Bob Smith','N','Y','Y' from dual union all
    select 'Tim Jones','N','Y','N' from dual union all
    select 'Fred Davis','Y','Y','N' from dual 
    )

select t.fam_nm, c.*, t.FLG Is_Applicable from camp_def c
join (
        select * from tgt 
        unpivot
        ( FLG for CAMP_NM in (Easy_Tennis, Summer_Vacations, CPR_For_Beginners))
    ) t
on upper(c.camp_nm) = t.camp_nm
```